# how to create 2 modals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two modal windows. The first one works correctly, the problem is in the second one, when I click the second <<open modal>>, it doesn't work. How can I make it so that when you click on the second modal, it starts working. while having only 1 block with id on the site.
this is html code with css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried many options, but each had some kind of jamb, I tried other scripts, for example, in one the text was not shown at all.

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Comment: @Andreas how to do with just one

Comment: _"I tried many options..."_ - Where's your most promising approach? What problems do you have with that approach? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas All of mine were unsuccessful.Unfortunately no codes, I delete them.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Andreas this is my second question here, I still don't understand much here

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="openModal1">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<button id="openModal2">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById("myModal1");
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal1");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
document.getElementById("openModal1").onclick = function() {
  modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
document.getElementById("openModal2").onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0].onclick = function() {
  modal1.style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1].onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal1 || event.target == modal2) {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: me need use 1 id